# How to dynamically set the name of @Measurement in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, influxdb

I tried to write data into InfluxDB2 using the POJO approach, and I want to use the field in the POJO as the value of measurement, here is my code,but it's not working. Can someone tell me the correct approach?

my evnironment:

- springboot: 2.3.8
- influxdb-client: 6.7.0

I tried using `#{measurementName}` to set the value of the name, but it is not working as expected. Instead of getting the value of the `measurementName` field, I am always getting the literal string `#{measurementName}`.

```java
@Bean
public InfluxDBClient influxDBClient() {
    return InfluxDBClientFactory.create(url,token.toCharArray());
} 

public void write(String bucket,String org,BillingNo billingNo){
    var writeApi = client.getWriteApiBlocking();
    writeApi.writeMeasurement(bucket,org,WritePrecision.NS,billingNo);

    client.close();
}

@Data
@Measurement(name = "#{measurementName}")
public class BillingNo {

    private String measurementName;
    @Column(tag = true)
    private Type type;

    @Column(tag = true)
    private String code;

    @Column(tag = true)
    private String sourceId;

    @Column
    private String info;
    @Column
    private boolean isRunning;

    @Column(timestamp = true)
    private Instant time;
    public enum Type {

        // product , combo
        PRODUCT, COMBO;
    }
}
```